# Represent a table as a matrix

Tags: python, database-design, data-structures, matrix

Suppose I have a database table with 3 fields: string title, int A, int B. 
A range of both A and B is 1 to 500.
I want to represent part of the values as a matrix 5x5.
So that (1, 1) will be string which has lowest both A and B; 
(5, 5) will have highest both A and B;
(1, 5) will have lowest A and highest B. And so on.
Which algorithm should I use?

Comment: Can you give as an example of what you want to do? I think I have not completely understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set up a simulation here and comments will describe the steps.

First I generate some data: a series of tuples each containing a string and two random numbers representing score A and B.

Next I divide the ranges of A and B into five equally spaced bins, each representing the minimum and maximum for a cell.

Then I serially query the data set to extract the strings in each cell.

There are a hundred ways of optimizing this, based on the actual data structure and storage you are using.

```
from random import random

# Generate data and keep record of scores
data = []
a_list = []
b_list = []
for i in range(50):
    a = int(random()*500)+1
    b = int(random()*500)+1
    rec = { 's' : 's%s' % i,
            'a' : a,
            'b' : b
             }
    a_list.append(a)
    b_list.append(b)
    data.append(rec)

# divide A and B ranges into five bins

def make_bins(f_list):
    f_min = min(f_list)
    f_max = max(f_list)
    f_step_size = (f_max - f_min) / 5.0
    f_steps = [ (f_min + i * f_step_size,
                 f_min + (i+1) * f_step_size)
                for i in range(5) ]
    # adjust top bin to be just larger than maximum
    top = f_steps[4]
    f_steps[4] = ( top[0], f_max+1 )
    return f_steps

a_steps = make_bins(a_list)
b_steps = make_bins(b_list)

# collect the strings that fit into any of the bins
# thus all the strings in cell[4,3] of your matrix
# would fit these conditions:
# string would have a Score A that is
# greater than or equal to the first element in a_steps[3]
# AND less than the second element in a_steps[3]
# AND it would have a Score B that is
# greater than or equal to the first element in b_steps[2]
# AND less than the second element in a_steps[2]
# NOTE: there is a need to adjust the pointers due to
#       the way you have numbered the cells of your matrix

def query_matrix(ptr_a, ptr_b):
    ptr_a -= 1
    from_a = a_steps[ptr_a][0]
    to_a = a_steps[ptr_a][1]

    ptr_b -= 1
    from_b = b_steps[ptr_b][0]
    to_b = b_steps[ptr_b][1]

    results = []
    for rec in data:
        s = rec['s']
        a = rec['a']
        b = rec['b']
        if (a >= from_a and
            a < to_a and
            b >= from_b and
            b < to_b):
            results.append(s)
    return results

# Print out the results for a visual check
total = 0
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        print '=' * 80
        print 'Cell: ', i+1, j+1, ' contains: ',
        hits = query_matrix(i+1,j+1)
        total += len(hits)
        print hits
print '=' * 80
print 'Total number of strings found: ', total
```

Comment: Thank you very match. You saved me a lot of time

Comment: Thanks @php5engineer -- I am sure you noted that this is a simplistic prototype and I am sure you would not want to query your database 25 times with every need to populate the matrix. But maybe that is the subject of a separate discussion :) Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have

```
title  A  B
one    1  1
two    1  2
three  2  1
four   3  3
five   4  4
six    5  5
seven  5  1
eight  1  5
```

and so on...?

Reduced to a 3x3 matrix it'll look like

```
a/b  1     2    3  
1   one   two  eight    
2   three four  ?
3   seven  ?   six
```

The question is, to what shall (2,2) point to? The average? Ok, and in a 5x5 matrix?
Your definition lacks some information.

An algorithm for the matrix above will be:

1. for A and B calculate min, max, avg
2. ask database for tuples (Amin, Bmin), (Aavg, Bmin), (Amax, Bmin) and so on
3. fill values into matrix

Add on: If you have no match, try ranges for min, max and avg.